# Illustrator how to edit the shape of a intersecting point of 3 thick lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm working in Illustrator and I've got trouble making the corner in the graphic look like the one in the original image, without those sharp things sticking out of the corner.  I need to keep those closed paths (marked with thick red line) so that they can be filled.

I've attached the graphic and a part of the original image.

Thank you.[image]

Comment: use round corners, the miter will always be off. Or buikd shapes out of the outer lines and fill separate pathless shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I selected that thick red path and went to effects/stylize/round corners, but it turned out really weird; I tried pathless shapes and filled them with white, it worked, but my graphic will be exported with a transparent background, not white. I tried filling them with transparency, but the blue underneath shows (that wasn't unexpected, doh...). Any ideas what to try next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "sharp things sticking out" are affected by 'miter'. I think joojaa was talking about the Corner 'round join' button in the `Stroke` palette (rather than the Rounded Corner effect). These issues only affect stroke - if you could have it as a filled object with no stroke that would solve this.

If you need to keep the stroke, a rounded join would solve this as it doesn't have sharp points. In that case, as the screenshot illustrates, the 'miter limit' box is greyed out. The 'limit' box adjusts the miter limit for sharp corners and can sometimes solve the issue (but not always).

[image]

If the thickness of the lines is okay and won't change, an alternative solution is to do 'Outline Stroke' to convert them to a filled object (without a stroke, so no sharp points sticking out).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Round join did the job and was so easy to apply. it took a long time to find an answer, and this was my first project, I'm glad it turned out ok. With that sharp things sticking out it would have looked very amateur.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked. Credit to joojaa too, as I just fleshed out the description. Please consider marking this as solved.